Ownership of OSObject passed to RequestDeviceConfigurationChange
If I call RequestDeviceConfigurationChange with an OBObject created with OSNumber::withNumber, where do I need to call release() on the OBObject object. The documentation of OSNumber::withNumber says that the retain count is 1.
auto* const newOSBufferSize = OSNumber::withNumber(in_io_buffer_frame_size, 32);
if (newOSBufferSize == nullptr) {
    return kIOReturnError;
}

if (RequestDeviceConfigurationChange(ConfigurationChangeType::OSBufferSize, newOSBufferSize) == kIOReturnSuccess) {
        newOSBufferSize->release(); // Xcode says "Potential leak of an object stored into 'newOSBufferSize' if this call is not made.
}
else {
    newOSBufferSize->release(); // Xcode says "Potential leak of an object stored into 'newOSBufferSize'" if this call is not made.
    return kIOReturnError;
}


kern_return_t CoreAudioDevice::PerformDeviceConfigurationChange(
  uint64_t change_action, OSObject* in_change_info) {
  switch (change_action) {
    case ConfigurationChangeType::OSBufferSize: {
      auto number = static_cast<OSNumber*>(in_change_info);
      // in_change_info->release(); Xcode says that "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller" if this call is made.
    ...
}


Does RequestDeviceConfigurationChange retain any OBObject that is passed, and release it after PerformDeviceConfigurationChange has finished?
